# Is there a way to correlate two gridded maps to compare their similarity?

Tags: python, correlation, cross-correlation

I want to perform a map based correlation of two gridded maps to determine how similar they are. Either giving a correlation coefficient or a map of correlation values.

I have a range of synthesised maps to correlate with a real map to figure out which ones match the best. The following code, shows the gridded data, zi and zi2 which I want to compare

`xi=np.linspace(min(x),max(x),200)
yi=np.linspace(min(yd),max(y),200)
zi = griddata((x, y), synth_data, (xi[None,:], yi[:,None]), method='cubic')
zi2 = griddata((x, y), real_data, (xi[None,:], yi[:,None]), method='cubic')`

would desire some sort of 2D correlation coefficient or cross correlation map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can flatten your 2d grids and then just apply pearson correlation.

An other approach zu see similarity ist just subtracting the two scalar fields and then sum the differences. This sum will be an indication for similarity, too.

My favourite approach zu calculate field similarity is described in [this paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/7321821).

Comment: Thanks I'll try it, and give that paper a read. I've done the subtracting method previously and now want to try some sort of correlation based method to see how the two methods compare

Comment: Do you know the syntax for applying pearson correlation to data in a map form. All I can find is how to apply it to x,y data?

Answer (score 0):

A correlation matrix is maybe what you're searching for. Here is an example.

```
numerical = list(set(df.columns) - 
                 set(['State', 'International plan', 'Voice mail plan', 
                      'Area code', 'Churn', 'Customer service calls']))

# Calculate and plot
corr_matrix = df[numerical].corr()
sns.heatmap(corr_matrix);
```